# Please suggest good book/website to for Threads and Concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have gone through Head First Java and some other sites but I couldn't find complete stuff related to Threads and additional concurrency packages at one place.

Please suggest a book/website which covers complete Threads with more details like

- Synchronize and locking of objects
- More detailed about volatile
- Visibility issues in Threads
- java.util.concurrent package
- java.util.concurrent.atomic package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The must-read book about concurrent programming in Java is [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Also see [Concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) in Sun's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [Java Concurrency Refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency) a useful aid along with [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://javaconcurrencyinpractice.com).

Answer (score 2):

Java Concurrency in Practice is great for coverage of the higher-level stuff in `java.util.Concurrent`, but if you want the authoritative answers on `synchronized` and `volatile`, you need to go to the source. No, not the source code, that would be insane. I mean the spec: [Java Language Specification, Third Edition — Chapter 17: Threads and Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html)

Or if you want it in book form: [The Java™ Language Specification (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246780)

Answer (score -1):

[Java Threads](http://books.google.com/books?id=mB_92VqJbsMC&lpg=PP1&dq=java%20threads&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) is another good one :)